# Running Tensorflow on GPU in WSL

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, I'm trying to get tensorflow to run on my Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060 GPU in wsl2 (Ubuntu 20.04.6) since the most recent versions of tf do not support running in native windows.

I've successfully installed CUDA version 12.3, and ran the CUDA sample deviceQuery, with the following output:

> CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)
>
> Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)
>
> Device 0: "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060"
> CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          12.3 / 12.3
> CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    7.5

... etc with info about memory

Running the nvidia-smi command likewise pulls up my info on my Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060. To my understanding, this says that my GPU is visible to the system. However, when I try to import tensorflow in python, I get the following message:

> 2023-11-20 16:15:02.569106: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
> 2023-11-20 16:15:02.601251: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
> 2023-11-20 16:15:02.601703: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
> To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
> 2023-11-20 16:15:03.224488: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT

I've successfully run pip install nvidia-tensorrt in an attempt to resolve that last line, and still had no luck.  This is the fourth or fifth night I've dedicated to this effort, so I'm getting a bit desperate.  Any help/advice would be very greatly appreciated!